# Illustrator text backround colored

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I'm fairly new to Illustrator and I have a question. It's the second time when a customer sends me a file (in this case a design of a business card) and when I open it in Illustrator the text's background looks like this:

[image: A capture]

Why is this background there? It has something to do with editing options? I don't even know how to call this and that's why I can't google it either.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is the Pink Highlighting for missing font. You should seen the pop-up when opening the file that some font are missing and your default one is used. 
It could be from totally different font or just different family or even when using the same font but on mac/win.